# Requested unknown parameter in Yarja Data Table

Tags: laravel, datatable

The Code in my controller is

```
       public function index(Request $request)
{
  $project_supervisor=  project_supervisor::with('project','superviser')->latest()->get();
  

  
        if ($request->ajax()) {
  $project_supervisor=  project_supervisor::with('project','superviser')->latest()->get();
        return Datatables::of($project_supervisor)
               ->addIndexColumn()
                ->addColumn('action', function( project_supervisor $data){ 
   
                      $button = '<button type="button" name="delete" id="'.$data->id.'" class="delete btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</button>';
                    $button .= '&nbsp;&nbsp;';
                    //$button .= '<button type="button" name="delete" id="'.$data->id.'" class="delete btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</button>';
                    return $button;
                })  
                          


                  ->addColumn('project_name', function (project_supervisor $project_supervisor) {
                return $project_supervisor->project->name;
                
            })


             ->editColumn('created', function(project_supervisor $data) {
                
                 return date('d/m/y h:i A', strtotime($data->created_at) );
                
            })

                ->rawColumns(['action','created' ])

                ->make(true);           

    }
  
    return view('project_supervisor.project_supervisor', compact('project_supervisor'));   

}
```

In my blade file , the code is

```
   var table = $('#patient_table').DataTable({
        
    
        
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        responsive: true,
    
        ajax: "{{ route('project.index') }}",
        columns: [
        
         {data: 'DT_RowIndex', name: 'DT_RowIndex'},
         
         
        
            
            
            
            {data: 'id', name: 'id'},
            {data: 'project_name', name: 'project.name'},


                {data: 'action', name: 'action'}, 
        ]
    });
```

It gives the following error message

> DataTables warning: table id=patient_table - Requested unknown
> parameter 'project_name' for row 0, column 2. For more information
> about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4

How can I fix the error

Comment: To be honest, your code is a mess and there is some duplication going on. That being said I can't really make sense of this. However what I noticed is you do ` {data: 'project_name', name: 'project.name'},`  shouldn't they both be `project_name` or should it be `name`?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is only by the name 'project.name' => 'project_name'
{data: 'project_name', name: 'project.name'},

You are trying to sort based in project name icons asc/desc in the table?

Answer (score 0):

datatable built in search doesn't work well with eloquent relationship and you get error for that

change you controller code to this :

```
   public function index(Request $request){

    $project_supervisor=  project_supervisor::with('project','superviser')->latest()->get();

    if ($request->ajax()) {
    $project_supervisors=  project_supervisor::select('project_supervisors.*','p.name AS project_name')
    ->leftJoin('projects as p','p.id','=','project_supervisors.project_id')
    ->leftJoin('supervisors as s','s.id','=','project_supervisors.supervisor_id')->latest();
    return Datatables::of($project_supervisors)
           ->addIndexColumn()
            ->addColumn('action', function( project_supervisor $data){ 

                  $button = '<button type="button" name="delete" id="'.$data->id.'" class="delete btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</button>';
                $button .= '&nbsp;&nbsp;';
                //$button .= '<button type="button" name="delete" id="'.$data->id.'" class="delete btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</button>';
                return $button;
            })  

         ->editColumn('created', function(project_supervisor $data) {
            
             return date('d/m/y h:i A', strtotime($data->created_at) );
            
        })

            ->rawColumns(['action','created' ])

            ->make(true);           

}

return view('project_supervisor.project_supervisor', compact('project_supervisor'));}
```

and change the blade file to this :

var table = $('#patient_table').DataTable({

```
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    responsive: true,

    ajax: "{{ route('project.index') }}",
    columns: [
    
     {data: 'DT_RowIndex', name: 'DT_RowIndex'},
     
     
    
        
        
        
        {data: 'id', name: 'id'},
        {data: 'project_name', name: 'p.name'},


            {data: 'action', name: 'action'  orderable: false,
                        searchable: false}, 
    ]
});
```

also notice that the custom column `action` dose not provide search option so you need to disable search and ordering function with  `orderable: false,searchable: false` for that column